# Blue Speech Bubble on Portrait

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I assume this means I should talk to Tybir and learn something, but I have no idea how to trigger it.

I've tried going through his dialog choices but nothing seems to remove the blue speech bubble. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: it happens with different party members, for various reasons, and it's just a bug, clearing itself after rest or leaving an area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when a blue speech bubble is available the character will talk about the topic as soon as you speak to him or her.

I've expereinced something like this as well with Aligern, I think it is a bug and the bubble disappeared after a crisis encounter.

Comment: I didn't notice if it was a crisis encounter or a rest that eventually removed it, but eventually Tybir did change his mind about talking (so I assume it was a bug).

Comment: I encountered that issue with Erritis on the newest patch, bubble disappeared after area transition